# Java regular expression, replace all content with braces inside

Tags: java, regex

I have requirement to replace everything inside the braces and including braces. I have wrote below regex to do that, but it is not working as expected. Some cases it is working, please see below.

1.

```
System.out.println(";;(||)||".replaceAll("(.*?)(?:\\(.*?\\))", ""));
```

Expected output  -  `;;||`

Actual - `||`

2.

```
System.out.println(";;||(||)".replaceAll("(.*?)(?:\\(.*?\\))", ""));
```

Expected output - `;;||`

Actual - nothing

Comment: not sure your rules, but you can try: `\\([^)]*?\\)`

Answer (score 0):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = ";;(||)||";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "")); // reluctant quantifier
    String s2 = ";;(||)|as|(hello)";
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", ""));
}
```

O/P:

```
;;||
;;|as|
```

Comment: @sp00m - No. You are right. Its not needed. Fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the first captured group index in the replacement part,

```
System.out.println(";;(||)||".replaceAll("(.*?)(?:\\(.*?\\))", "$1"));
System.out.println(";;||(||)".replaceAll("(.*?)(?:\\(.*?\\))", "$1"));
```

**Output:**

```
;;||
;;||
```

**What actually  the below code will do?**

```
System.out.println(";;(||)||".replaceAll("(.*?)(?:\\(.*?\\))", "$1"));
```

This regex `"(.*?)(?:\\(.*?\\))"` would match only the substring `;;(||)` and then it captures and stores  `;;` into group 1. All the matched characters are replaced with the characters inside the captured group 1(ie, `;;`). so `;;(||)` would be changed into `;;` and nothing happens on the following `||` substring . Thus finallly it gives the output as `;;||`

Answer (score 0):

This simple ony should suit your needs: `[(][^)]+[)]`. Replace all occurrences with an empty string.

PS: `[(]` has the same meaning as `\(`, which I find more readable. Especially in Java, because you have to escape the backslashes since in string literals (`\\(`).

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    System.out.println(";;(||)||".replaceAll("\\((.+?)\\)", ""));
```

The result is:

```
;;||
```